# Creating a sublist of objects after these objects are modified in a recyclerview

Tags: java, android, list, android-recyclerview

I am building a shopping cart method,i get a list of objects from the response, add it to an adapter (Recyclerview.Adapter). each object has its quantity,and in the viewholder,i have one plus button and one minus button,when clicked i change the object quantity. 
When i finish clicking plus and minus buttons, (after having left some objects in a certain quantity) i press a Check shopping cart button. When i press that button,I need to have a sublist of the modified version of list at the adapter,contanining only the objects with positive quantity.
This is my code so far:
 buttons at my ViewHolder:

```
  @OnClick(R.id.item_items_order_now_plus)
    public void onAddItemClicked() {
        ShoppingCartList.getInstance().increaseTotalSize();
        dataItem.increaseQuantity();
        shoppingCartListChanged.smthChanged();
        plusclicked++;
        previouslyRemoved = true;
        ShoppingCartList.getInstance().getShoppingCartItems().add(getAdapterPosition(), dataItem);
        if (plusIncreaseNumber.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            plusIncreaseNumber.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        plusIncreaseNumber.setText(plusclicked + "");

    }

    @OnClick(R.id.item_items_order_now_minus)
    public void onRemoveItemClicked() {
        if (plusIncreaseNumber.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            return;
        }
        if (plusclicked > 0) {
            dataItem.increaseQuantity();
            ShoppingCartList.getInstance().decreaseTotalSize();
            plusclicked--;
            plusIncreaseNumber.setText(plusclicked + "");
        }
        if (plusclicked == 0) {
            if (previouslyRemoved) {
                ShoppingCartList.getInstance().getShoppingCartItems().remove(getAdapterPosition());
            }
            plusIncreaseNumber.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return;
        }


    }
```

ShoppingCartListClass:
(for saving the total number of items to display them and to work with only one list)

```
public class ShoppingCartList {
    private static ShoppingCartList shoppingCartList;
    private static int totalSize;
    private ShoppingCartList(){

    }
    public static ShoppingCartList getInstance(){
        if (shoppingCartList==null){
            shoppingCartList=new ShoppingCartList();
        }
        return shoppingCartList;
    }

    private static List<al.baboon.restaurant.restsapp.response.dashboardReport.specificCategoriesResponse.DataItem> shoppingCartItems=new ArrayList<>();
    public List<al.baboon.restaurant.restsapp.response.dashboardReport.specificCategoriesResponse.DataItem> getShoppingCartItems(){
        return shoppingCartItems;
    }
    public static int getTotalSize(){
        return totalSize;
    }

    public static void increaseTotalSize(){
        totalSize++;
    }
    public static void decreaseTotalSize(){
        if (totalSize>0){
            totalSize--;
        }
    }
    public static void emptyTotalSize(){
        totalSize=0;
    }

}
```